# Is there a way to compare the old password if it's hashed?

Tags: asp.net, hash, asp.net-membership, change-password

I am using the ChangePassword web control in order to change the user password. my provider is using hashed password, and I am want to keep using it. 
just wanted to know if there is a way to compare the current password the user entered with the old password in the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Membership.ValidateUser method, that returns true or false, depending on whether the entered password - in your case the new password - is the same as the old password.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.validateuser.aspx

Answer (score 0):

hash the current password and compare it.. thats how it is ususally done